# ssh to linux home computer, without configuring the router: possible at all?

Tags: linux, networking, router, ssh, remote-access

There are many tutorials on how to setup a linux computer at home so you may connect to it remotely via ssh, but they require to do some configuration on the router.

Is there any way to setup ssh (or ssh like) communication without any configuration on the router ? (i.e. just configuring the computer, and then just plugging it via ethernet to the router).

(here would be an awful way to do this: having the computer continuously downloading some file from a server, file which may contains commands to execute. The computer would then execute the command, and upload a file with its output. The remote computer would have a convenient interface to write/read files on the server. I can only guess far better/safer ways exist).

Comment: You can use a [reverse ssh tunnel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work). Of course you need control over at least one machine which has an open SSH port

Comment: You could also use a vpn with a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably lots of ways to achieve your end goal, including the idea of using a reverse ssh tunnel, allowing you to hop through a secondary server that does have an open port.  One way, as described in the comment, requires you to have one internet facing computer.

Another similar approach still uses a tunnel, but through a third party.  One such publicly available tunneling option is CloudFlare's Tunnel.  [Here's one reasonable tutorial.](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/tunnel-guide/)

Another, definitely more complicated approach would be to use [NKN Peer-to-Peer networks](https://nkn.org/), which can be setup to behave much like the CloudFlare tunnel.